How is the synchronization delay of MPI applications modeled using the LogGP family of models?
MPI applications incur synchronization costs when the send operation must wait for the receive operation to be posted. The LogGP model has overhead parameters but they are not meant to model this synchronization delay. The subsequent LogGPS[1] model does take into account this delay, but it is not clear from the original paper how this delay is estimated.
I want to know how to estimate this delay so as to build an accurate model of MPI communication.
I have read multiple papers on this and in most of them, the authors usually mention that the parameters are empirically determined from micro-benchmarks. However, this delay can be random and using a benchmark will only give a deterministic value.
[1] https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/568014.379592
